# Возвращение JSON данных

Tags: php, javascript

У меня есть массив, который извлекается из файла(В массиве на данный момент около 400 элементов)

```
$html = implode('', file('id.txt'));
$arr = explode("###", $html);
```

Пробую его посмотреть при помощи echo json_encode($arr); 
Но возвращает [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null...]
В чём проблема?

Comment: формат файла что ли приведите, и используйте `file_get_contents()` вместо `file()`, ибо нет смысла разделять файл на строки, а потом склеивать обратно

Comment: может изначально файлик переименовать в id.json?)

Comment: Не совсем по теме, но используйте json для хранения данных в файле, очень удобно, можно быстро преобразовать в массив и обратно.

Comment: @teran в файле содержится  Дачная###Двухъярусная кровать "Точенка - 2"###Дача###Икея###Каролина и т.д.